# arcGISMapImageLayer works in WPF, not in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I am trying to get an overlay working in Xamarin Forms (all code in shared folder) with Esri.ArcGISRuntime SDK v100.1.0 for .NET, testing with Android as start-up project.  I load an ESRI basemap, then add a busmap/transitmap (from our own GIS server) as a layer on top of that. When I monitor the layerviewstatus, it goes from “loading” to “error”.   I do get the basemap to display, but nothing is overlayed.

If I try the sample layers hosted by ESRI, like the census overlay, it works fine.

I can get the same code to display the layers in WPF, but not in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: What is the Error property returning on the LayerViewState object? This should give you a hint what is wrong. For instance one scenario could be your device doesn't have access to the server (network, authentication, ssl issues etc)

Comment: dotMorten:  Thank you, I did discover layerviewstatus.error property, and it gives me:  "System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A…"   Is there a way to see the whole error message?

Comment: What is a code snippet that can be used to demonstrate this?

Comment: If you get an aggregate exception, take a look at the inner exception or the exception list of the aggregate exception, and their messages. It definitely sounds like a connection issue from your device.